# Performance and design difference between an object and a primitive

Tags: java, python, types, dart

I feel like most of languages tends to justify that they are object oriented with statement like "Everything is an object" like ruby and dart.

On the other hand statement like this (Java Complete Reference)

> The primitive types represent single values—not complex objects.
>   Although Java is otherwise completely object-oriented, the primitive
>   types are not. They are analogous to the simple types found in most
>   other non–object-oriented languages. The reason for this is
>   efficiency. Making the primitive types into objects would have
>   degraded performance too much.

So why does other languages implement primitives as objects?

Comment: performance? You have may noticed many of the "everything is an object" languages are not actually efficient, CPU and memory wise. The only reason they appear okay is that many of the functions are hidden, implemented in other languages such as C - while Java does everything by itself, e.g. math, encoding conversion, string and collection operations, etc. However, it's actually possible with the bytecode form to support "everything is an object", by examining the use of certain variables/fields and transforming/JIT the code accordingly (primitive or object).